# Prove $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b) = ab / \gcd(a,b);\ $ $\gcd(a,b) \le |a - b|$ for $a \ne b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

What's the simplest proof that the least common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is equal to the product of $a$ and $b$ divided by the greatest common divisor, i.e.:

$$\operatorname{LCM}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{gcd(a,b)}$$

and that

$$\gcd(a,b)\le |a-b|,\ \ {\rm for}\ \ a\neq b$$

Note: $ $ the original version was: $\ \,\gcd(a,b) < |a-b|,\,$ but that has trivial counterexamples, e.g. see the comments below.

Comment: The second is false, let $a=b=1$ or let $a=2$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Is it true in this form: $gcd(a,b)\leq |a-b|$?

Comment: @chenh. $\gcd(1,1) = 1 > 0 = |1-1|$, so no.

Comment: It is true with $\le$ and $a\ne b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = \prod{p_i^{k^a_i}} \wedge b = \prod{p_i^{k^b_i}}$, then note that:

$$\begin{align*}\begin{split}
ab &= \prod{p_i^{k^a_i + k^b_i}} \\
\gcd(a, b) &= \prod{p_i^{\min(k^a_i,~k^b_i)}}\\
\mathrm{LCM}(a, b) &= \prod{p_i^{\max(k^a_i,~k^b_i)}}
 \end{split}\end{align*}$$

Now transform LCM:
$$\begin{align*}\begin{split}
\mathrm{LCM}(a, b) &= \prod{p_i^{\max(k^a_i,~k^b_i)}}\\
&= \prod{p_i^{(k^a_i + k^b_i) -\min(k^a_i,~k^b_i)}}\\
&=\prod{\frac{p_i^{k^a_i+k^b_i}}{p_i^{\min(k^a_i,~k^b_i)}}}\\
&=\frac{\prod{p_i^{k^a_i+k^b_i}}}{\prod{p_i^{\min(k^a_i,~k^b_i)}}}\\
&=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}
\end{split}\end{align*}$$

Second thesis isn't true. But you can prove $\gcd(a,b) \leq |a-b|$ for $a\neq b$. Assume that $gcd(a,b) = d \wedge a' = \frac{a}{d} \wedge b' = \frac{b}{d}$ and note $a \neq b \Longrightarrow a' \neq b'$, then

$$\begin{align*}\begin{split}
&\left(\left(|a'-b'| \neq 0 \wedge a',b' \in \mathbb{Z}\right) \Longrightarrow
|a'-b'| \geq 1 \wedge\\
|a-b| = |d\cdot a' - d \cdot b'| = d |a'- b'|\right) \\
&\Longrightarrow
|a-b| = d |a'- b'| \geq d = \gcd(a,b) \Longleftrightarrow\\
&|a-b| \geq gcd(a,b)
\end{split}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks. Is the second true if a and b are distinct and greater than 2??

Comment: @chenh. Not good enough, $a=m$ and $b=2m$ fail for any $m>0$.

Comment: You need $\leq$ and $a\neq b$ to make it work.

Comment: @JoshuaBiderman It wrote *André Nicolas* in [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023083/proof-about-relation-between-the-least-common-multiple-and-the-greatest-common-d/1023183?noredirect=1#comment2087294_1023083) and proof to this is in my answer...